# CYPRESS_NO_COMMAND_LOG=1 while running Cypress in headless mode

Tags: cypress

I am trying to disable logging in cypress by setting `NO_COMMAND_LOG=1` in env file (cypress.env.json). It works in headed mode (cypress runner), but doesn't seem to work in headless mode. I am  using `npx cypress open`. Tried running via package.json as well using `npm run cy:run`, no luck either. Am I missing something in headless mode? Any pointers to disable the logs in headless mode will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try running this in the terminal: "CYPRESS_NO_COMMAND_LOG=1 npx cypress run"

Regards!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).